# Loop python code

Tags: python, loops, iteration

```
self.textboxAnswer1.resize(100,50)
self.textboxAnswer2.resize(100,50)
self.textboxAnswer3.resize(100,50)
self.textboxAnswer4.resize(100,50)
self.textboxAnswer5.resize(100,50)
self.textboxAnswer6.resize(100,50)
```

Is there a way to put this code into a loop to become more efficient, it seems very repetitive.

using python

Comment: You can put the texboxAnswers in a list and iterate over it.

Comment: Don't use variables like this. Use a data strcutrue like a list to store your text boxes. _Then_, it would be trivial to use a loop: `for textbox in self.textboxes: textbox.resize(100, 50)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access class attributes by getattr:

```
for i in range(6):
    getattr(self, 'textboxAnswer{}'.format(i)).resize(100,50)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the formulation of your object, but in this case (under the hypothesis I cannot modify the object for any reason) you can actually use the `__dict__` and a regular expression:

```
import re

class T:
  def __init__(self):
    self.option1 = "1"
    self.option2 = "2"
    self.notthis = 3

  def test(self):
    for k in self.__dict__:
      if re.compile("option").match(k):  # selects only the attributes that start with "option"
        print(self.__dict__[k])  

t = T()
t.test()
```

It prints:

```
1
2
```

It is ugly and inefficient but does its job. **If** you **can** change how the attributes are stored in your object (using a list, a tuple, or any other collection), then follow that way, please.

Applied to you case it would be (rember to import `re`):

```
for k in self.__dict__:
  if re.compile("textboxAnswer").match(k):
    self.__dict__[k].resize(100, 50)
```

Answer (score -1):

Stick the `textboxAnswer`s in a loop, then just loop over it:

```
textboxes = # Add all the textboxes into a list here

for tBox in textboxes:
    tBox.resize(100,50)
```

Comment: I got rid of the `var`. Not sure why I added that. Had JS in my head for some reason.